# Is there a special way to cut off sunchoke flowers?

Tags: vegetables, flowers, sunchoke

My sunchokes are starting to flower, is there a special way to cut the flowers off, or should I just cut off the heads when they emerge from the foliage?

Comment: Nothing special, just clip off buds and flowers with a pair of shears (not sure what you call them over there) just taking the tops off, or a pair of secateurs if you've got plenty of time and nothing much to do...

Comment: @Bamboo there should be a video of you showing this ;) ;)

Comment: Sunchokes are considered an invasive weed by many - and rightfully so, IMHO. It's far more difficult to harm them than by  just snipping off the tops "the wrong way", if there is a wrong way at all.

Comment: @blackthumb - a video? it would be deeply boring, though mercifully brief! it ain't rocket science, just get out there and cut off the tops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the flowers (to boost yield), all you need is to get them before the buds open. You can use whatever you want (I used scissors last time if I remember correctly). I suppose you could pinch/twist them off by hand if they are young, as long as you don't break a main stem.